# The distance of $y$ from $A$ equals $||y-\overline y||$?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

> Is the following true in $\Bbb R^n$?
>
> If $A$ is  a one-dimensional subspace spanned by $u$ then for any vector $y\in \Bbb R^n$ the distance of $y$ from $A$ equals $||y-\overline y||$
> where $\overline y$ is the othogonal projection of $y$ on $u$.

I know that the othogonal projection of $y$ on $u$ is $ y=\frac{\langle y,u\rangle }{\langle u,u\rangle } u$

Also $y-\overline y$ is  orthogonal to $u$.

I have proved these.

But how to prove or disprove the above ?Please help

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** For any $x\in A$, we have $\|y-x\|^2 =\|y-\bar y\|^2+\|\bar y-x\|^2$.